# Not able to configure where is the problem: 'urllib' is not defined

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib, urlopen

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_American_films_of_2021"

source = urllib.request.urlopen(link).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
```

> NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined

Comment: Please provide complete error message rather then just one line.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be with the way the library is imported.

You could either do like

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request as req

link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_American_films_of_2021"

source = req.urlopen(link).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
```

Or

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs
import urllib

link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_American_films_of_2021"

source = urllib.request.urlopen(link).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
```

Or

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs
from urllib.request import urlopen

link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_American_films_of_2021"

source = urlopen(link).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
```

Comment: I don't think that should be the issue here, cuz if I import any library then it should work perfectly, working perfectly! And I know OP should do that but what OP is doing is also right?

Comment: yes, importing as the OP has done normally would work but may not be the preferred way. Also, assuming (based on the error)  this is not the full code and the OP is using urllib somewhere else as well and using it this way makes it easier to figure that out.

Comment: The code above works for me but how does it not work for OP..? Do you have any clue on why bro?